# Fire a tag depending on datalayer variable value

Tags: google-tag-manager

In Google Tag Manager I succeed to:

- push a datalayer variable with a given value
- create a custom varaible named "DLV Dep"

```
<script>
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  window.dataLayer.push({'dep': '84'});
</script>
```

I failed to fire a tag depending on this datalayer variable value.
Here is what I've done:

- I created a custom HTML tag (simple console.log script)
- Associate to a triger > page view > custom variable  "DLV Dep" =  "84"

In my debug window I can see the DVL Dep with value 84, but tag never fire.

Comment: Did you make sure that your dataLayer push was before the GTM snippet? Else the page view event will happen before the variable is populated, and the script cannot fire. Also the debugger shows in pretty much detail which conditions are met and which fail in the trigger if you click on the details for the tag.

Comment: I switch to DOM Ready instead of "Page View" and it solve my problem.
So in a way yes you were on the good track. Thanks for your comment